# Showing data labels in MS Chart Control's COLUMN graph at the CENTER of the COLUMNS

Tags: c#, vb.net, charts, mschart

I want to show the data labels on graph using MS Chart Control at the center of the COLUMNS (as shown in below diagram).

Can anyone please let me know how can I achieve this? I saw  there is an "Angle" property which allows to rotate the series label but didn't get the property which will allow me to set the label "position" at the CENTER of the column COLUMNS.

[Image showing how I want to show the data labels in MS Chart Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfRc7.jpg)

Regards!
Swad

Comment: I don't think you can. You could try to set the Labels for each DataPoint prefixed with a varying number of blanks, but that's rather hackish..

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in support for this, you *can* however create the functionality yourself using the Chart.PostPaint event. From PostPaint you can access the chart graphics to draw white boxes and rotated text, this is by no means an easy task to do properly (Not sure about finding the center of bars). I suggest you start by looking up PostPaint to see if it's worth the effort or not.

Some resources on topic to get you started:

- [Tutorial: Customizing a Chart with Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456612.aspx)
- [StackOverflow: c# chart vertical text annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404193/c-sharp-chart-vertical-text-annotation) See 2nd edit for rotation