# How to rotate a text in rectangle shape C#

Tags: c#, zxing, qr-code

I have made an application which generates me a QR Code in a PNG image, and prints out the text from QR image, but now I need to rotate that text 90 degrees and I can't find a way to do this...I think that the rectangle must be rotated because the text it's inside this rectangle.

Example:
[image]

Code:

```
namespace QR_Code_with_WFA
{
    public void CreateQRImage(string inputData)
    {
        if (inputData.Trim() == String.Empty)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data must not be empty.");
        }

        BarcodeWriter qrcoder = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter
        {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new ZXing.QrCode.QrCodeEncodingOptions
            {
                ErrorCorrection = ZXing.QrCode.Internal.ErrorCorrectionLevel.H,
                Height = 250,
                Width = 250
            }
        };

        string tempFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + inputData + ".png";

        Image image;
        String data = inputData;
        var result = qrcoder.Write(inputData);
        image = new Bitmap(result);
        image.Save(tempFileName);

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tempFileName);

    var result2 = qrcoder.Write(inputData);

    int textWidth = 200, textHeight = 20;
    // creating new bitmap having imcreased width
    var img = new Bitmap(result2.Width + textWidth, result2.Height);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 12))
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
    using (var bgBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))
    using (var format = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near })
    {
            // filling background with white color
            g.FillRectangle(bgBrush, 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height);
            // drawing your generated image over new one
            g.DrawImage(result, new Point(0,0));
            // drawing text
            g.DrawString(inputData, font, brush,  result2.Width, (result2.Height - textHeight) / 2, format);
    }

    img.Save(tempFileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply a [`RotateTransform`](https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=graphics.rotatetransform) on the `Graphics` object before drawing the text:

```
// Change alignment to center so you don't have to do the math yourself :)
using (var format = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center })
{
   ...
   // Translate to the point where you want the text
   g.TranslateTransform(result2.Width, result2.Height / 2);
   // Rotation happens around that point
   g.RotateTransform(-90);
   // Note that we draw on [0, 0] because we translated our coordinates already
   g.DrawString(inputData, font, brush, 0, 0, format);
   // When done, reset the transform
   g.ResetTransform();
}
```

Comment: If I use this the text will disappear

Comment: That's because you'll also have to use `Graphics.TranslateTransform`, otherwise you're rotating around [0, 0] and so your text is not visible anymore. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rotate full `Graphics`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662(v=vs.110).aspx

Similar topic:

[Rotated text align in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460258/c-rotated-text-align)